# Configuring a VPN to both act as a client and a server

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dd-wrt, vlan

Ideally I would like to have a network setup where my internet traffic would be anonymized through Private Internet Access's VPN service.

I would like to set this up on my dd-wrt router so the traffic from all devices connected to that router would be sent through the VPN.

Simultaneous to this VPN client connection, I would like to set up a VPN server connection on the network using a VPN-server-capable wired router.

This way I can access my home network when I'm away. I was unsure about any issues regarding setting the two up simultaneously and whether or not crosstalk(?) would be an issue.

Is there another way to accomplish the goal of anonymizing home network traffic while also being able to access that same network from outside of it?

Comment: Hi JohnC, can you please clarify where the server part of this comes in? Do you have a 2nd router providing the VPN service on the network? Or is it a functionality of your first dd-wrt router? (Specifically, what do you mean by "using one of the preexisting VPN server capable wired routers"?)

Comment: I was looking at [this router](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124518) in parallel(?) with the dd-wrt router. I was unsure who would be in charge of dhcp. Am i complicating a process that can be fully accomplished by one router?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be possible.

Routing out-going web traffic through one VPN is completely distinct from being able to offer an incoming VPN connection to the private network.

Comment: Suppose he has 5 computers on his LAN. How many VPN  clients would he need?

Comment: Of the external VPN? 1. He has the dd-rt router as the only client.

Comment: +1 oh great. that sounds like part of what he's after then. So I suppose the DHCP of the DDWRT router would hand out the IPs it gets from the VPN server.   He can always try to additionally set up a VPN server on his router or another.

Comment: `hand out the IPs it gets from the VPN server` -> That's not quite how I was imagining it; I had assumed the dd-rt router is a gateway to the remote VPN. It takes 1 IP from the remote VPN. All traffic sent from the LAN will appear to come from that single address from the remote VPN's perspective.

Comment: ah ok, I haven't set one up but what you say sounds more like how it'd work